# External d3.sankey: d3 is not recognized - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

I'm trying to incorporate the following sankey example into a django project: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5028304

I have all my javascript in external sheets, and am calling them in javascript.html which is being pulled into my base.html.  The problem is that the sankey.js file is not recognizing d3.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined(anonymous function) @ sankey.js:22
(index):83 Uncaught TypeError: d3.sankey is not a function**

Part of my actual code for sankey.js is as follows:

```
$.getScript("../static/js/d3.js", function(){
   alert("d3 loaded but not necessarily executed.");
});
$.getScript("../static/js/d3.min.js", function(){
   alert("d3.min loaded but not necessarily executed.");
});
$.getScript("../static/js/d3.v3.min.js", function(){
   alert("d3.v3.min loaded but not necessarily executed.");
});
d3.sankey = function() {
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your call to `d3.sankey` inside the callback from `$.getScript`.

Or just use the `.done()` function. e.g :

```
$.getScript("../static/js/d3.v3.min.js")
.done(function() {
     d3.sankey = function() {} // Call your logic here
});
```

This way, `d3` should be defined before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

After an unnecessary long time of tinkering I realized i was calling my sankey.js script before calling d3.v3.min within my javascript.html.

To solve, I just moved my d3.v3.min library above my sankey.js call.

Thanks!!!